# How to parse in Roslyn a given statement string into a StatementSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have a List of StatementSyntax type called "statements" where I would like to insert into a statement like "var obj = new object();"

I tried:
ExpressionSyntax  es = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression("var obj = new object();")

but I can't insert it in the list throwing an exception "can't convert ExpressionSyntax (or SyntaxNode)" to StatementSyntax.

```
ExpressionSyntax  es = SyntaxFactory.ParseExpression(                                        
     declaredStat.Declaration.Type.ToFullString() + " " +
     declaredStat.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault().Identifier.ValueText +
     " = String.Empty;"
);

statements.Insert(0, es);
```

it throws exception in the above line.

I would like that the statement given as a string,  to go in a certain index of the List, so the final goal to be:

BlockSyntax block= SyntaxFactory.Block(statements.ToArray());

but I can't build statements with a list of statements inserting a statement from a given string.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. When posting code, use the button "code sample" to improve the question's appearance

Comment: You have a `List<StatementSyntax>` and you're trying to insert an `ExpressionSyntax` object. That's a different type of object than your list, so you need an explicit cast, or you need to change your `List` e.g., perhaps both `StatementSyntax` and `ExpressionSyntax` implement an interface and you could do `List< your interface >`?

Comment: I was hoping Roslyn may provide a call like

 StatementSyntax  newStatement = SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement("var o = new object()";
myList.Insert(index, newStatement);

Comment: Have you tried [SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntaxfactory.parsestatement?view=roslyn-dotnet)?  Also note that assigning `String.Empty` to a variable of a random type is probably going to cause problems.

Comment: D Stanley, I just can't believe it.... I already guessed it above in my help that it should be a call like SyntaxFactory.ParseStatement(), and it never showed up in IntelliSense, even though I almost never use var yet MS IntelliSense didnt suggest this method for a StatementSyntax variable, .....I was so upset with Roslyn they didn't offer something so "obvious".....  as soon as I typed it manually, it found the method as normally anyone would have guessed...  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a ExpressionSyntax object on a List of StatementSyntax. Why don't you create a list of ExpressionSyntax and insert the new ExpressionSyntax object on that list?

Comment: I have a bunch of API calls that return block of statements which are found in blocks of diff Syntaxblocks e.g. if(){}, usings(){}, or  methods(){}, they all do have  returntype as List of StatementSyntax

Comment: Try to reformulate your question. I'm thinking is not clear.

Comment: Probably I should, btw D Stanley answered what I was looking for. I am new here, not sure how to call his answer as the "right one"

Comment: You cant because he not answered, he just commented. But you can upvote his comment.

Comment: All I can see is a Flag, and I don't think is the right one... I can't find the upvote button!

Comment: Is because you need 15 points to upvote a comment. So you will need to wait @D Stanley or post you own answer